# Easiest way to access Google Contacts on Android

Tags: android, google-contacts-api

I need to basically create an Android app which accesses the contact information of a fixed Google account. If I'm not mistaken, it seems the GData API doesn't work on Android, while the Portable Contacts API doesn't support ClientLogin (which seems to be a lot simpler than OAuth). Do I have to use Portable Contacts + OAuth, or is there an easier way?